# Not able to redirect output of the command to a file

Tags: python-2.7, os.system

My problem is after executing below code I am able to see outputs of each command in shell. How can I get that shell output to the file

I have tried with the below but it does not work

python pr.py >> pr.txt

```
 import os

 f=open("pr1.txt","r")
 df=0
 for i in f:

     df=df+1
     if df==4:
        break
     print i
     os.system("udstask expireimage -image" + i)
```

After executing "os.system("udstask expireimage -image" + i)" every time this will display status of the command to the file

Comment: You should use a single `>` AFAIK.

Comment: Tried but not redirecting :)

Comment: Can you paste the content of `pr1.txt` or it is completely empty...`strange`? In my case, it is working. `>>` for appending & `>` will override the content (By default, both create the file first time if it does not exist).

Comment: Below is the output I am getting 


[09:54:17] cse-cds2n1:/dumps/tmp # python /dumps/tmp/pr.py >> /dumps/tmp/asd.txt
ACTERR-010016 image does not exist: Image_38317735
ACTERR-010016 image does not exist: Image_38317736
ACTERR-010016 image does not exist: Image_38318636

Comment: So this is the content of `pr1.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like :

```
import os

f=open("pr1.txt","r")
 df=0
 for i in f:

     df=df+1
     if df==4:
        break
     print i
     os.system("udstask expireimage -image" + i + " > pr.txt")
```

It would redirect the output of the command to pr.txt.

You should use `subprocess` instead of `os.system` which has more efficient stream handling and gives you more control while calling a shell command:

```
import os
import subprocess

f=open("pr1.txt","r")
 df=0
 for i in f:

     df=df+1
     if df==4:
        break
     print i
     task = subprocess.Popen(["udstask expireimage -image" + i],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
     task_op = task.communicate()
     task.wait()
```

Now you have your output stored in `task_op` which you can write onto a file or do whatever you wish to. It is in tuple form and you may need to write only required part.